# Why using Jsoup.connect("someurl").get() has different result from the "view page code" or the "inspect element" in chrome

Tags: http, jsoup

If I print the document got from Jsoup.connect("someurl").get(), it will have a action of a form as

`/login.do;sessionid=74667165451B52E3B25B8C48A1B1655711?action=doLogin.`

But if check the "view page code", or the "inspect element", it has only the following without the sessionid

```
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="/login.do?action=doLogin">
```

Why there are different, isn't browser a page is a get method?

Comment: Without the specific website address and analysis of what is going on on the network level it is hard to answer your question

Comment: Most likely some dynamic page content through JavaScript that Jsoup can't execute.

Answer (score 0):

There are two (possible) causes:

1. The Website may use (java-)**script** or similar; Jsoup doesn't support those, therefore nothing executed
2. The Website has **different views** for eg. mobile's, browsers etc. (you get a page depending on your user agent)

To see what applies here, you can print the document and look for user agent tests (like scripts in the beginning of the source) or javascripts at the expected position. You also can set another user agent (eg. firefox) and test again.

But as *luksch* said in the comments: Without more information it's hard to answer this question.